# IE Overwrite window.top

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to convince a page that it is the window.top even though it is in an iframe.

In FF you can do

window.**defineGetter**('top', function() { return window});

in Webkit (Safari/Chrome) you can simply do

window.top = window

but in IE none of those methods work.  Anyone done this before?

Comment: window.top=window doesn't work on Chrome. (it does work on Safari). see: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting window.top doesn't work.  Its not allowed in IE.

I ended up having to make my own fake window object, fill it with most of the properties of the window object, and then making a fake .top property.

Answer (score 1):

I'd maybe try using the "define getter" notation that John Resig uses in his [article on the topic](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/):

`Window.prototype.__defineGetter__('top',function(){return this;});`

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.top = window.top.window`

More details on [DOM Window](http://w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_window.asp).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. 

The issue is that IE throws an error when trying to set window.top (or even window for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "parent", { 
        get: function() {return window;} 
    }
);
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__).