# Hiding or replacing window.top value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm trying to hide the `window.top` property from a page that it's included in an *iframe*.

Basically, I want this *iframe* can access to it's parent window with `window.parent` and can also know that itself is an *iframe*, but it has to be convinced that its parent window is the top window.

I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/573824/995958), and I achieved desired behaviour using:

```
Window.prototype.__defineGetter__('top', function() { return window.parent; } );
```

This piece of code is in the *iframe*. I'm developing both frame and parent, so I'm able to edit all I want.

The problem is that this does not work on IE (all versions). I'm not searching a IE equivalent for that code, I'm only interested to the final goal. And I'm opened also to the ugliest hacks/idea you can imagine.

Comment: @jasssonpet This throws an access violation error.

Comment: @lorenzo-s did you find any solution to your question?

Comment: @mwweb sorry, after 6 years I don't even remember why and where I needed that. Anyway I guess I didn't found anything because I did not left a reply here.

Comment: @lorenzo-s because `window.top` is readonly. anyway .. do you  think creating a popup the window.top will get the value of popup url?